# check if a number is an Armstrong number java

Tags: java

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Please enter a number:"+" ");
    Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
    long number=scan.nextLong();
    String num=String.valueOf(number);   // simple way to get the number of digits in a number
    long sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<num.length();i++)
    {

        sum+=Math.pow(num.charAt(i), num.length());

    }

    if(sum==number)
    {
        System.out.print(number+" "+"is an armstrong number");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print(number+" "+"is not an armstrong number");
    }
}
```

i need to know what is wrong with this code, the sum line is not working properly. for example if i enter the number 371 (Armstrong number) the output of the sum suppose to be 371 but the output that appears according to my code is 416675371

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you're applying the `Math#pow` on the ASCII code of the character returned from `num.charAt(i)` rather than the digit itself. To retrieve the digit itself rather than the ASCII representation then 
use `Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i))` instead of `num.charAt(i)`.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I hope my updated answer accomplishes your comment.

Comment: Definitely an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is just find the difference between the char and the ascii value of '0':

```
for(int i=0;i<num.length();i++)
{
    sum += Math.pow(num.charAt(i) - '0', num.length());
}
```

**Note**: The ascii value of '0' (the digit) is 48

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
sum += Math.pow(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(num.charAt(i))), num.length());
```

**How It Works**:

Suppose you have the number `371` which consists of `3` digits, so when you get the String value `num` by invoking this method `String.valueOf(number);` on the number inputted, the String `num` will have a length of `3`.

Now in the `for loop`, in every round, it will calculate the power of each digit after reading it as a `char` at every index specified by `i` [`num.charAt(i)`], then reading it as a`String` [`String.valueOf()`], finally parsing it as an `Integer` [`Integer.parseInt()`].

At the end of every loop, the calculation will be added to the `sum` variable.

Comment: @YoussefAbdeen If you have any question about this code please don't hesitate akhi :)

Comment: @YoussefAbdeen You're more than welcome, if it helped you please accept it :)